# PHP post request to retrieve JSON

Tags: php, json, post, httprequest

I'm trying to write some simple php code that will make a post request and then retrieve a JSON result from the server.
It seemed simple to me, but the below code simply doesn't open a connection.

```
$port = 2057;
$path = "/validate/";
$request = "value1=somevalue&value2=somevalue&value3=somevalue";

$http_request  = "POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$http_request .= "Host: $server\r\n";
$http_request .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;\r\n";
$http_request .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($request) . "\r\n";
$http_request .= "\r\n";
$http_request .= $request;

$response = '';

if( false == ( $fs = @fsockopen($server, $port) ) ) {
            die ('Could not open socket');
}

fwrite($fs, $http_request);

while ( !feof($fs) )
{
    $response .= fgets($fs, 1160);
}

fclose($fs);
```

In addition I've tried a more simple approach with:

```
$handle = fopen('http://localhost:2057/validate/?'.$request, "r");
```

or

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://localhost:2057/validate/' . $request);
```

but both of these approaches just time out.

I'm trying to connect to a development server I'm running in Visual Studio, so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the timeout/connection issues.

Open to any suggestions here as long as they are built in PHP.

Comment: do you have telnet installed? If not take a look [here](http://www.leateds.com/2009/telnet-for-windows-vista-windows-7/). try to connect to your host via telnet, to see if the host is reachable, if not it could be a firewall problem.

Comment: I can write a similar query in JS and have no trouble reaching the host, so I don't think its a firewall problem.

Comment: is it safe to assume in the first example you didn't copy the line that says $server = "localhost";?

Comment: Do you have access to the web server logs? I frequently run PHP on systems that has something akin to SELinux installed. Generally speaking, it won't even let you get a file handle unless its been explicitly told to, much less open a TCP connection. Can you tail the httpd logs while you are doing this?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of pure-PHP HTTP handlers out there that might work better for you.

Try [PEAR's HTTP_Client](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Client) or [Zend_Http_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html), both of which you can simply bundle with your application.

If you're dead-set on writing your own, try working with [streams](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php).  There's a [comprehensive set of HTTP stream options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/); it's not in standard PHP, but you can distribute it with your application so you don't have to worry about whether it's installed or not.

The following is a snippet from a class I use to POST a document to a conversion server; you can post whatever you like and get the results in a similar way.

```
$request = new HTTP_Request2('http://whereveryouwant:80/foo/');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST)
    ->setConfig('timeout', CONVERT_SERVER_TIMEOUT)
    ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
    ->addPostParameter('outputFormat', $outputType);
$request->addUpload('inputDocument', $inputFile);
$result = $request->send();
if ($result->getStatus() == 200) {
    return $result->getBody();
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to write this by using the http extension : http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-data.php

Comment: I really bet that it would be however we'll be distributing this and we can't guarantee that people will have extensions so it all has to be in core PHP.

Comment: You can distribute Pear modules with your code however; try looking at HTTP_Request2, I use it to submit POST requests and retrieve data easily; I'll post some sample code below if you're interested.